# Get items count by key name

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have these records in a MySQL DB. On a JSON type column.

```
Record1: {"images": ["image.jpeg", "image.jpeg"]}
Record2: {"images": ["image.jpeg", "image.jpeg", "image.jpeg"]}
Record3: {"images": ["image.jpeg"]}
```

How can I get the total count of images by the key name of the JSON property which in my case is 'images'?

I am trying to achieve the same thing as running this below query, but counting the array items from the images key.

```
SELECT
  `field`,
  count( * ) AS total 
FROM
  `table_name` 
WHERE
  `condition`
GROUP BY
  `something`
```

which will give you this result:

```
field      total
------------------
field1       5
field2       2
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
 field      total
 -----------------
 images       6
```

#### Table structure

[image: Table structure]

#### Table data

[image: table data]

Comment: do you want it by php or query ?

Comment: Just mysql query will be ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  `type`,
  SUM(
    JSON_LENGTH(`media`, '$.images')
  ) `media`
FROM
  `table_name`
GROUP BY
  `type`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5df7ff731b7819df393fd51301d90411).

Comment: Yes, this is what I was after. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

ok sure You can use this query :

```
SELECT type,JSON_LENGTH(media) FROM `tabl4` group by type
```

check the execution from here : [Demo](https://paiza.io/projects/1NtatBhaYX1nVhyYg7e0oA?language=mysql)

Comment: It is not doing what is supposed to do. I just want to get the count of all images inside the 'media->images' grouped by type.

Comment: No, 8 actually because there is the last record wich is type 1 and has 2 images

Comment: i think that what this query make check the demo to understand

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working on my local machine. Could it be because the media column is JSON type on my local? Also image.jpeg was just an example. The data will have different image names with different extensions and this query will not work with that.

Comment: ah yeh imm i think yes try to change it to varchar or text its better

Comment: Still doesn't work, don't know why, but anyway I cannot change the column type from JSON to varchar so I will need a solution for JSON type column. I see that there are some [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html) on MySQL website but I just can't figure it out... And also like I said above I need a JSON type solution and also bare in mind the images are not same name and extension.

Comment: I don't get an error I just get the count as 0 on all types if I change the column type to varchar, but like I said in the above comment I will need a solution for JSON type column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185358/discussion-between-codrin-and-hamzanig).